# Oracle select from dual with multiple rows and columns

Tags: oracle, dual-table

I need to join against a dynamic list of numbers that I retrieve from my program dynamically. The number of rows is not fixed, nor are the numbers that are used.

I am not finding a better way to accomplish this than with the following (for my purposes, a temporary table is not helpful):

```
select 111 as col1, 322 as col2 from dual
union all
select 3 as col1, 14 as col2 from dual
union all
select 56 as col1, 676 as col2 from dual;
```

Is there a better way to do this? I see that there is a connect by statement that can return multiple rows, but I'm not seeing a way to do multiple rows and columns.

Comment: it it really the pattern {1,2},{3,4},{5,6}?

Comment: No, it's a set of numbers I get programmatically. I don't know what the numbers are beforehand.

Comment: You could build a PL/SQL collection then select from `table(collection)`. Sorry I don't have time to write an example. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2065746

Comment: How will this query be used?  It usually doesn't make sense to have a query that returns an unknown number of columns so I assume you have some unusual need here.

Comment: rows, sorry. question edited.

Answer (score 8):

**You can use the decode and connect by level:**

```
select decode(rownum, 1, 111, 2, 3, 3, 56) as col1,
       decode(rownum, 1, 322, 2, 14, 3, 676) as col2
  from dual
connect by level <= 3;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `CONNECT BY` here with a little math:

```
SELECT Level * 2 - 1 AS col1, Level * 2 AS col2
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```

That will give you your example of three rows. Adjust the `LEVEL <= ...` value to get more rows.

---

**Update 2022**: I see that the OP edited the question the day after my answer, making it invalid.

B. Khan's answer a year later is more on point, though honestly I prefer `CASE` over `DECODE` -- `DECODE` is more compact but IMO `CASE` is more readable. I also prefer `LEVEL` over `ROWNUM` here because `ROWNUM` doesn't always work the way one would expect.

```
SELECT
  CASE LEVEL
    WHEN 1 THEN 111
    WHEN 2 THEN 3
    WHEN 3 THEN 56
    END as col1,
  CASE LEVEL
    WHEN 1 THEN 322
    WHEN 2 THEN 14
    WHEN 3 THEN 676
    END as col2
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not looking for a specific pattern--I've updated the question to indicate that. Props for the clever solution, though.